# Function with generic type

Tags: swift, generics

I have a function that can calculate the sum of numbers in array with condition like so:

```
func sumOfArrayWithCondition(array: [Int], filter: (element: Int) -> Bool) -> Int {
    var result = 0
    for i in 0..<array.count where filter(element: array[i]) {
        result += array[i] 
    }
    return result 
}
```

Now I want it to work with `Int, Float, Double` type. I have tried, but didn't work.

```
protocol Addable {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Int: Addable {}
extension Double: Addable {}
extension Float: Addable {}

func sumOfArrayWithCondition<T: Addable>(array: [T], filter: (element: T) -> Bool) -> T {
    var result = 0
    for i in 0..<array.count where filter(element: array[i]) {
        result += array[i] // <-------- Error here
    }
    return result // <-------- Error here
}
```

But it says:

> Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'T'

So how to do it.

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that `result` is an `Int`. It should be a `T`. I also think you need to add `func +=(inout lhs: Self, rhs: Self)` to your protocol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First issue is that the compiler is inferring the type `Int` for the var `result` because you don't declare a type and initialize it with `0`.  But you need `result` to be of type `T`.

First, in order to initialize `result` as an instance of type `T` with the value `0`, you need to specify that `Addable` is also `IntegerLiteralConvertible`, which is already true for `Int`, `Double` and `Float`. Then you can declare `result` as type `T` and go from there.

As Rob pointed out, you also need to add the `+=` function to your protocol if you want to be able to use it.

So the final code that achieves what you are looking for is:

```
protocol Addable : IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func +=(inout lhs: Self, rhs: Self)
}

extension Int: Addable {}
extension Double: Addable {}
extension Float: Addable {}

func sumOfArrayWithCondition<T: Addable>(array: [T], filter: (element: T) -> Bool) -> T {
    var result:T = 0
    for i in 0..<array.count where filter(element: array[i]) {
        result += array[i]
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer really helps me.

Comment: You shouldn't do the `..<` there.  Just use direct iteration:  `for elem in array where filter(element: elem) { result += elem }`.  It's much cleaner that way

Answer (score 4):

As Rob said, result is an Int.  But there's no need to create that method at all.   You're wanting to call that like so, based on your method signature:

```swift
let sum = sumOfArrayWithCondition(myArray, filter: myFilter)
```

instead, all you have to do is use existing methods provided by swift:

```swift
let sum = myArray.filter(myFilter).reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
```

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I have tried this `filter(myFilter).reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }`, but I still want try to create a function similar like this :) (for learning). But as always, I will upvote your answer for your help.